# When we should edit the title of a question?

Tags: discussion

I think that a title like this: [Is this reaction to produce ammonium sulfide safe?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9634/is-this-reaction-safe) is not good because do not contain any information regarding the reaction, so I would like to edit it in something like this :"Is safe to produce Ammonia Sulfide mixing ammonia and head matches?" I think that good title can be useful for the visibility of the site in Search engine indexing and so for the site health. Should we edit titles more often?

Comment: Yes, you should always edit to improve if possible :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should absolutely edit titles to be as descriptive as possible.  Make sure to check the body of the post as well to see if it needs any fine tuning.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would try to edit as few as possible to try to keep the information as provided by the OP.

The question you are referring to has a title that says nothing at all. That might also cost some attention for the question itself. In this case I would suggest the edit, to make it more interesting to all of us. It is also quite good to have meaningful titles if we would like to refer to it in other posts.

As the OP will be notified s/he could roll back any time.